# C++ Multidimensional Array

Tags: c++

i'm trying to figure out how to fill a multidimentional array in this way:
Input: rows = 3 , cols = 3 :

```
1 4 7
2 5 8
3 6 9
```

can somebody give me an idea?

P.S My task is to find how many nubers stay in the same position in both arrangements. Ex:

```
1 4 7       1 2 3
2 5 8       4 5 6
3 6 9       7 8 9
```

so the numbers that are in the same position are : 1 5 9. 
i've tryied :

```
//n = 3 , m = 3
for(int i = 0; i <n; i++) {
for(int j = 0; j <m; j++){
if(array[i][j] == array2[i][j]) {
lol++;
}
}

}
cout<<lol;


/*
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9


1 4 7
2 5 8
3 8 9
*/
```

it must show me 3 , but it shows 0, where is the problem?

Comment: I'm curious, did you put any effort into solving this problem before posting? I know the answer, but why duplicate code that can be found in 30 seconds with a simple Google search? Oh, and if you don't like Google, here is the direct link: http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/articles/7459/

Comment: I gave you the code. `int i = 1; i <=n` is different than `int i = 0 ; i < n`

Comment: @LuchianGrigore oh i missed that. But now, the main problem is , how to find those numbers that i explained in the description..

Comment: @ddacot have you even debugged the code?

Comment: @LuchianGrigore somehow i did it [ http://ideone.com/1pIWT ]. But when i input 3 and 6 , the program crashes..

Comment: you're iterating the other way around. You have array[n][m] but i goes from 0 to m, and j goes from 0 to n. So you try to access array[m][n]. Switch i and j.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Are you sure you meant to @ me and not ddacot?

Comment: @ddacot: Your attempt at reverse psychology is not impressive. Just because someone shows you that the answer to your question is easily found on the interwebtubes doesn't mean he doesn't already know the answer himself. And telling people to "gtfo" whilst you're demanding free help with your problems is not going to get you very far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Populate at initialization:

```
int a[3][3] = { { 1, 4, 7},
                { 2, 5, 8},
                { 3, 6, 9}
              };
```

EDIT (unsure if resolved):

After update to question here is an example application that (with modification to accept input from user) will diff two arrays and construct an array indicating the elements that were the same and a count of the number of identical elements:

```
#include <iostream>

int** make_array(const size_t a_rows, const size_t a_columns)
{
    int** result = new int*[a_rows];
    for (size_t i = 0; i < a_rows; i++)
    {
        *(result + i) = new int[a_columns];
    }
    return result;
}

void print_array(int** a_array, const size_t a_rows, const size_t a_columns)
{
    for (size_t r = 0; r < a_rows; r++)
    {
        for (size_t c = 0; c < a_columns; c++)
        {
            std::cout << *(*(a_array + r) + c) << " ";
        }
        std::cout << "\n";
    }
    std::cout << "\n";
}

int main()
{
    // Example data.
    int a[3][3] = { { 1, 4, 7},
                    { 2, 5, 8},
                    { 3, 6, 9}
                  };
    int b[3][3] = { { 1, 2, 3},
                    { 4, 5, 6},
                    { 7, 8, 9}
                  };
    size_t rows    = 3;
    size_t columns = 3;

    // Create three arrays:
    //  - two input arrays
    //  - array that represents which elements are the same
    int** in_1 = make_array(rows, columns);
    int** in_2 = make_array(rows, columns);
    int** diff = make_array(rows, columns);

    // Populate with example data.
    for (size_t r = 0; r < rows; r++)
    {
        for (size_t c = 0; c < columns; c++)
        {
            *(*(in_1 + r) + c) = a[r][c];
            *(*(in_2 + r) + c) = b[r][c];
        }
    }

    // Diff.
    // The 'diff' array will hold '1' for elements that
    // were the same and '0' for elements that were not.
    size_t same_count  = 0;
    for (size_t r = 0; r < rows; r++)
    {
        for (size_t c = 0; c < columns; c++)
        {
            *(*(diff + r) + c) = *(*(in_1 + r) + c) == *(*(in_2 + r) + c);
            same_count += *(*(diff + r) + c);
        }
    }
    std::cout << "\n";

    // Results.
    print_array(in_1, rows, columns);
    print_array(in_2, rows, columns);
    print_array(diff, rows, columns);
    std::cout << "Same element count: " << same_count << "\n";

    // Free...

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
$ ./cpp/main.exe

1 4 7
2 5 8
3 6 9

1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9

1 0 0
0 1 0
0 0 1

Same element count: 3
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a dynamically allocated array if you only know the dimensions at runtime:

```
int** x = new int*[rows];
for ( int i = 0 ; i < rows ; i++ )
   x[i] = new int[cols];
```

And then populate it:

```
for ( int i = 0 ; i < rows ; i++ )
for ( int j = 0 ; i < cols ; j++ )
   x[i][j] = y;
```

Or better yet, use a vector of vectors, this will give you more flexibility:

```
std::vector<std::vector<int> > x;
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution would be this:-

```
int k = 1;
for(int i = 0; i < row; i++){
  for(int j = 0; j < col; j++){
    a[j][i] = k; // filling it in the column first order
    ++k;
  }
}
```